# Quote formatting not applied in chat transcripts

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Prefixing a singe-line chat message with `>`  causes it to be displayed as quote, but this formatting isn't applied in the transcript. [See this message for an example](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/821881#821881).

#### In Chat

[image]

#### In Transcript

[image]

Comment: Ugh, this drives me crazy. I brought it up in Chat Feedback before but nothing came of it, let's hope it gets fixed this time around.

Comment: @Tim calm your rage... I'm looking at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should now work; note that (re your example) we apply the same rules here as in the main room; only the single-line-with-space version is supported.

Comment: \o/ I can rest easy now. Well, except for all the other reasons I don't rest easy, but your taking care of this great injustice is much appreciated.

Comment: @Tim you wouldn't rest so easily if you knew that.... *I'm watching you right now*...

Comment: I am actually kind of unsettled now, my side bar claims you [posted something in the Sandbox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fhxQz.png), but there's nothing there. :o