# Blockquotes don't render in bookmarked chat conversations

Tags: bug, chat, blockquote, chat-bookmarks, conversation

When reading a bookmarked chat conversation, blockquote formatting doesn't work (the > shows up as if it was plain text). Here's an [example conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/conversation/testing-quotes-in-bookmarks):

[image: unrendered blockquotes in chat messages from a bookmarked conversation]

It [doesn't break](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119257/quote-formatting-not-applied-in-chat-transcripts) in the [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58864009#58864009) or in the live chatroom.